# (very large) div display disappears after certain width (about 10 mil px)

Tags: html, css, width

I have a VERY wide element, but past around 10mil pixels, the div stops displaying (although it is still clickable and interactable)

Here is an image of the end of the div:
[image]

Is there any workaround to this? I am creating a video timeline, and, as you can see, the timeline element becomes very large when we zoom all the way in to specific frames.

And, if this is something there is no fix for, does anybody know of any way to virtualize width? (allowing me to still display the scrollbar but only render each in-View section at a time, to get around this overflow issue?)

There's a lot going on in my code, but here is the html of my timelime:

```
<div 
    id="component-container"
    (scroll)="updateActiveFrameRange()"
>

    <div 
        id="timeline" 
        tabindex="0"
        (focus)="OnFocus()"
        (blur)="OnBlur()"
        (keydown)="OnKeyInput($event)"
        (click)="OnTimelineClick($event)"
        (wheel)="handleScroll($event)"
    >

        <div 
            id="playhead"
            (mousedown)="movePlayheadByMouse()"
        >
                <span id="playhead-marker">&#9930;</span>
                <div id="playhead-line"></div>
        </div>

        <div 
            id="time-section"
        >   
            <div *ngIf="this.inTimeCode">
                <measure-line 
                    *ngFor="let frame of this.measureLineArray"
                    [frame]="frame"
                    [timeCode]="getTimeCode(frame)"
                    [leftPos]="frameToPx(frame)"
                    [labelInterval]="this.labelInterval"
                    [displayTimeCode]="true"
                >
                </measure-line>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="!this.inTimeCode">
                <measure-line 
                    *ngFor="let frame of this.measureLineArray"
                    [frame]="frame"
                    [leftPos]="frameToPx(frame)"
                    [labelInterval]="this.labelInterval"
                    [displayTimeCode]="false"
                >
                </measure-line>
            </div>

        </div>

        <md-divider>

        <div 
            class="track-section">
        </div>

        <md-divider>

        <div 
            class="track-section">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

As well as the relevant CSS:

```
#component-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#timeline {
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#playhead {
    margin-top: 34px;
    // This height variable should always be === (3 * the number of track-section elements) + 8
    // This can be done in the .ts file in response to an event that represents adding a track section
    height: 108px;
    width: 1px;
    color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;

    #playhead-line {
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 100%;
        width: 1px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #playhead-marker {
        height: 12px;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: -8px;
        user-select: none;
    }
}

#playhead:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#playhead-marker:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.md-tooltip {
    user-select: none !important;
}

#time-section {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.track-section {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Finally, here is the Typescript function that adjusts the width:

```
private handleScroll(event : WheelEvent) : void
    {
      if (event.deltaY < 0)
      {
        // Assigning maximum zoom to be when the timeline displays 29 or less frames
        if (this.Container.scrollWidth / this.Container.clientWidth >= this.numFrames / 29)
        { 
          console.log("hit max");
          return;
        }
        else 
        {
          this.zoom *= 1.5;
        }
      }

      if (event.deltaY > 0)
      {
        // Minimum zoom ratio is 1
        if (this.zoom > 0.8)
        {
          this.zoom *= 0.8;
        }
      }

      // Store information before zooming to be able to recalculate new position after zoom
      let prevMouseOffset = event.clientX - this.Container.offsetLeft;

      let prevMouseOffsetRatio = (event.clientX - this.Container.offsetLeft + this.Container.scrollLeft) / this.Container.scrollWidth;

      // Zoom!
      this.Timeline.style.width = Math.ceil(this.startingTimelineWidth * this.zoom) + "px";

      // Set scrollLeft to maintain the frame the mouse was previously on
      this.Container.scrollLeft = (this.Container.scrollWidth * prevMouseOffsetRatio) - prevMouseOffset;

      this.OnZoomUpdated();

      this.renderTimeline();

      console.log(this.Timeline.clientWidth);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Doest it have background image? Do you use overflow:hidden? You need to show your code, in order to get help, showing screenshot is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, since my project code has a lot of unrelated material, I thought I would omit it. If it's too much to read through, I can create a Plunkr or JSFiddle when I have time to try and recreate the behavior in a simpler environment.